# Spring Boot integration mybatis annotations error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I run the following program I receive the following error. How can I solve it?

> Description:
>
> file [E:\program\github\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\mapper\UserMapper.class] required a single bean, but 4 were found:
>       - &userMapper: defined in file [E:\program\github\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\mapper\UserMapper.class]
>       - systemEnvironment: a programmatically registered singleton    - contextParameters: a programmatically registered singleton    - contextAttributes: a programmatically registered singleton
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
>
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58011', transport: 'socket'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Here is my Spring Boot config file `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456

mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.example.demo.entity
```

DemoApplication.java  -- bootstrap class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@MapperScan(value="com.example.demo.mapper")
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("add")
    public void add(User user) {
        userService.addUser(user);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

entity -- `User.java`

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private int userId;

    private String username;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Service -- `UserService.java`

```
public interface UserService {

    void addUser(User user);

}
```

Service implementation -- `UserServiceImpl.java`

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userMapper.insert(user);
    }
}
```

Mybatis interface -- `UserMapper.java`

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    @Insert(
            value = "insert into user values(#{user.userId},#{user.username})"
    )
    void insert(User user);

}
```

Comment: did u find a solution to this ?

Comment: version problem

Comment: Can you please share the correct version matching?